# Writing TXT file from pandas DataFrame for position-based columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to write a position based text file from a Dataframe with varying column widths.Say my DF is

```py
data=np.array([[9,df_transformed.shape[0],dfsum['Col2'],ff]])
hdrftr_conv=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['RcdType','RcdCount','DRSum','FillerCol'])
```

```
 RcdType  RcdCount  DRSum          FillerCol
0   9      4      166088867670352        ...
```

The txt file needs to have same 4 columns but position should be as below:

```
Col          Start Position   End Position
---                  
RcdType        1               1
RcdCount       2               7
DRSum          8               25
Filler         26              863
```

Tried different ways, using Tabulate etc but doesn't seem to be quite flexible. Appreciate ur response.

Rgds,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **np.savetxt** with formatting & other options.